# can we declare nested class object in main function

Tags: c++, class

I am pretty new to this nested classes in c++ ,and i was trying one program
in which it is clearly mentioned that declare the object of inner class or nested class inside main function. After declaring object of nested class inside main method it shows an error "b was not declared in this scope" .Please tell how to declare nested class object inside main method.

```
   class a

    {
      public:

       class b

           {
             //something
           };
    };


     int main ()      

     {

      a obj1; //object of outer class

      b obj2;//can we declare the object of nested class b in side main fuction?

      return 0;
     }
```

Comment: What is the access specifier for `b`?

Comment: First of all, `b` is private by default. Also, you need to use `a::b` to refer to `b` because `b` is a member of `a`.

Comment: access specifier for b is public.

Comment: Then use `a::b obj2;`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
class a
{
    //something
public:
    class b
    {
        //something
    };
};


int main ()      
{
    a obj1; //object of outer class

    a::b obj2;//declare the object of nested class b in side main function

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that class b must be public within class a, in order to be used outside of class a.
Also notice how the declaration of obj2 specifies that b is in the scope of class a.
This assumes that both classes have a public default constructor.